# Strange Error on website (maybe 303 error?)

Tags: php, google-chrome, safari, web

I have a strange problem with a website in PHP but it will happen only in Chrome and Safari when I access the base URL of the website.

Example 1: When I write on Chrome the address of the site `www.generaledil2000.it` I got a white page and in console log I got `Failed to load resource` but if I write the full address to the index page `www.generaledil2000.it/index.php` the website is displayed fine and all is okay.

Example 2: In safari at the address `www.generaledil2000.it` I got this error `cfurlerrordomain:303` and at the address `www.generaledil2000.it/index.php` no error.

In IE and Firefox all is working fine.

What's the problem? It's a hosting problem? I don't have any other file index than index.php in root folder.

**UPDATE:** Maybe it's a JavaScript error but I don't know how to fix it.

PS: On localhost with easyphp5.3.9 work without any error

Comment: This sounds like a javascript problem. Not PHP. (*"failed to load resource"*) What resource is failing to load?

Comment: its working on my chrome but i have to refresh the page. is this the problem?

Comment: Works fine for me in chrome/safari using Windows 7.

Comment: @Matt i don't know what resource is failing to load.. GET http://www.generaledil2000.it/  http://www.generaledil2000.it/:14

Comment: @baig772 yes, it's the error.. if you refresh the page you'll able to see the site.. on chrome i'm also on win 7

Comment: it's a javascript error.. thank you for the suggest... if i disable javascript website load fine without error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by using an `.htaccess` file with this content:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```